# Why doesn't XOrg do both configuring automatically and loading configuration files?

Tags: xorg

As you can see in the current implementation of [`InitOutput()` of xf86Init.c](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/blob/xorg-server-21.1.8/hw/xfree86/common/xf86Init.c#L322), XOrg doesn't do both configuring automatically and loading configuration files at the same time. (Correct me if I am wrong.)

Why did they implement it this way? I think it would be better to merge settings from static files and automatic configuration. I want to know the history of this design decision. (I expect they have good reasons for that.)